# Magento 2: Caches to enable for frontend dev

Tags: magento2, cache, frontend

Most backends I've worked with usually work with most or all caches enabled. Frontend development on Magento 2 is problematic with such a configuration, since a lot of the work relies on making changes and refreshing the browser often.

I have found from personal experimentation that disabling all caches apart from `config` and `eav` allows for workable performance while still allowing changes to propagate to the frontend.

Are there any other cache configuration changes that could be made which would improve performance without impeding workflow?

Comment: personally i just disable full page cache on dev server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just beginning.

Symlinks can be tricky because they don't refresh - they link to core when you add new file as js or html.

Varnish can be disabled for local domains.

Disabling cache in backend are the most important with switching to develop mode.

Additional check `op_cache` and other provided in system cache solutions.

Disable front cache in developer tool (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development).

Localstorage is next layer. It is used to store session data as customer, cart etc.

Comment: Yes, the symlinks issue frustrates me too. I don't generally override core JS files, but when overriding core .html templates I've found I need to manually rm those files from pub/static.